# InstaPy - like by tags

Tags: python, instagram, keyerror, instapy

I have been running Instapy with no problem, other features such as unfollowing, following, and watching stories and reels all still work. The issue I am having is with liking by tags. The error message I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/em/PycharmProjects/instabot_1/test_1_likes.py", line 61, in <module>
    session.like_by_tags(random.sample(like_tag_list, 3),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instapy/instapy.py", line 1977, in like_by_tags
    inappropriate, user_name, is_video, reason, scope = check_link(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instapy/like_util.py", line 618, in check_link
    media = post_page[0]["shortcode_media"]
KeyError: 0
```

I am running Instapy via Firefox, Pycharm, and I use a Mac. I am a newbie with Python.

This is the code I am running...

```
import random
from instapy import InstaPy
from instapy import smart_run
browser = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'



# login credentials
insta_username = 'myaccountname'
insta_password = 'mypassword'

dont_likes = ['sex', 'nude', 'naked', 'beef', 'pork', 'seafood',
              'egg', 'chicken', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'lobster',
              'fisch', 'schwein', 'lamm', 'rind', 'kuh', 'meeresfrüchte',
              'schaf', 'ziege', 'hummer', 'yoghurt', 'joghurt', 'dairy',
              'meal', 'food', 'eat', 'pancake', 'cake', 'dessert',
              'protein', 'essen', 'mahl', 'breakfast', 'lunch',
              'dinner', 'turkey', 'truthahn', 'plate', 'bacon',
              'sushi', 'burger', 'salmon', 'shrimp', 'steak',
              'schnitzel', 'goat', 'oxtail', 'mayo', 'fur', 'leather',
              'cream', 'hunt', 'gun', 'shoot', 'slaughter', 'pussy',
              'breakfast', 'dinner', 'lunch']

#friends = ['list of friends I do not want to interact with']

like_tag_list = ['vegan', 'veganfoodshare', 'veganfood', 'whatveganseat',
                 'veganfoodie', 'veganism', 'govegan',
                 'veganism', 'vegansofig', 'veganfoodshare', 'veganfit',
                 'veggies']

# prevent posts that contain some plantbased meat from being skipped
ignore_list = ['vegan', 'veggie', 'plantbased']

accounts = ['accounts with similar content']

# get a session!
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,
                  password=insta_password,
                  headless_browser=True)

with smart_run(session):
    # settings
    session.set_relationship_bounds(enabled=True,
                                    max_followers=15000)

    #session.set_dont_include(friends)
    session.set_dont_like(dont_likes)
    session.set_ignore_if_contains(ignore_list)

    session.set_user_interact(amount=2, randomize=True, percentage=60)
    session.set_do_follow(enabled=True, percentage=40)
    session.set_do_like(enabled=True, percentage=80)

    # activity
    session.like_by_tags(random.sample(like_tag_list, 3),
                         amount=random.randint(50, 100), interact=True)

    session.unfollow_users(amount=random.randint(75, 150),
                           InstapyFollowed=(True, "all"), style="FIFO",
                           unfollow_after=90 * 60 * 60, sleep_delay=501)

    
session.end()
```

Comment: Up, I've just got this error and could figure this out yet. Have you already solved it?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to the changes that Instagram has made in its source code.
Go to line `619` from the `like_util.py` (REFER TO YOUR SYSTEM ON WHERE INSTAPY FILES ARE LOCATED) file and change that part of the code to the code I gave you below (if you could not find this part of the code, the phrase `media = post_page[0]["shortcode_media "]` Search the file `like_util.py`)

```
     media = post_page ['items'] [0]
     is_video = media ["is_unified_video"]
     user_name = media ["user"] ["username"]
     image_text = media ["caption"] ["text"]
     owner_comments = ""
```

After that, you'll run into another error `Could not find followers' for ... Grabbed 0 usernames from....`

FIX for these errors (works for me at least, please backup and test yourself):

File: `xpath_compile.py`

Line 111-117:

FROM

```
xpath["get_given_user_followers"] = {"followers_link": "//ul/li[2]/a/span"}

xpath["get_given_user_following"] = {
    "all_following": "//a[contains(@href,'following')]/span",
    "topCount_elements": "//span[contains(@class,'g47SY')]",
    "following_link": '//a[@href="/{}/following/"]',
}
```

TO

```
xpath["get_given_user_followers"] = {"followers_link": "//ul/li[2]/a/div/span"}

xpath["get_given_user_following"] = {
    "all_following": "//a[contains(@href,'following')]/div/span",
    "topCount_elements": "//span[contains(@class,'g47SY')]",
    "following_link": "//a[contains(@href,'following')]/@href",
}
```

Line: 97-104

FROM

```
xpath["get_following_status"] = {
    "follow_button_XP": "//button[text()='Following' or \
                                  text()='Requested' or \
                                  text()='Follow' or \
                                  text()='Follow Back' or \
                                  text()='Unblock' and not(ancestor::*/@role = 'presentation')]",
    "follow_span_XP_following": "//button/div/span[contains(@aria-label, 'Following')]",
}
```

TO

```
xpath["get_following_status"] = {
    "follow_button_XP": "//button/div[text()='Following' or \
                                  text()='Requested' or \
                                  text()='Follow' or \
                                  text()='Follow Back' or \
                                  text()='Unblock' and not(ancestor::*/@role = 'presentation')]",
    "follow_span_XP_following": "//button/div/span[contains(@aria-label, 'Following')]",
}
```